# Is Istio or AWS App mesh for service mesh implementation on EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, istio, amazon-eks, aws-app-mesh

We are building up product which will have set of microservices communicating with each other.
We are using EKS as kubernetes service from aws. For Service mesh, There are two ways to go for it.

1. Install Istio over EKS cluster.
2. Use AWS App Mesh service with EKS.

The more I read about it, There are its own advantages of using one over other but not sure which one to go with.
Istio is more matured whereas App Mesh is able to integrate with different AWS services like XRay, Cloudwatch etc. easily.

Any inputs over this is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This may lead to highly opinionated answers and usually this doesn't fly well on Stackoverflow. As you pointed out there isn't a specific answer other than "it depends". Your own background, organization goals, requirements etc. count more than the point opinion of individuals for this.